# Bundle IDs I've deleted are still showing up in iTunes Connect

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

Since iTunes Connect started allowing us to delete unwanted Bundle IDs, I've deleted a bunch that I didn't want to use (by clicking on the id, clicking "edit", and scrolling to the bottom to click the "delete" button), and they are no longer visible in the developer portal; however, when I go to register a new app in iTunes Connect, they are still visible in the dropdown of Bundle IDs.

Over the years, enough of them have built up and I cannot see the Bundle ID that I want to select, presumably because there are a bunch of unused, deleted IDs that are showing up instead.

They don't bother me all that much, but I can't pick the ID that I need. Why are they still showing up in iTunes Connect?

---

I'm referring to the "Bundle ID" dropdown here:

[image]

---

*I'd post more screenshots, but there is some relatively sensitive information there, so we'll have to do without in this case.*

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a localized issue, but I've contacted support. I'll update this question as I get more info from them.

Comment: Just thinking aloud. 1- Did you look for the app in iTunes Connect or are you sure that you did not start creating the app?. 2- As far as I know, iTunes Connect doesn't forget many things: so, if you created a bundle id, you may delete it from your dashboard, but it may still be there in Apple's servers forever.